# Dtd XML Elements in any order and any number

Tags: xml, dtd

I need to write a dtd for the first time. I have being reading for a while and the only solution I could come up to have any number of elements of any type is the following.

```
 <!ELEMENT sentence ((word?,punc?)*)>
```

It looks very fishy to me. Does anyone know a better way? Does this really does what I want?

Thanks in advance

Altober

Comment: Note that for any elements *e1, e2, ... eN,* an expression of the form `(e1?, e2?, ..., eN?)*` is equivalent to `(e1 | e2 | ... | eN)*` (and many people regard the latter as clearer).  Can you explain what seems 'fishy' about the construct you show?

Answer (score 2):

You could use `ANY`...

```
<!ELEMENT sentence ANY>
```

This will allow any element any number of times in any order. This will also allow #PCDATA though. In addition, you will still need to have a declaration for any element that appears in `sentence`.

If you know which elements will appear in `sentence`, you could write the declaration like this instead:

```
<!ELEMENT sentence (word|punc)*>
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried that one but it did not work, is weird. It seems OK to me and it fails with simple data.

Comment: @Altober - Is there an error message? If not, what is the failure?

Comment: Yes it says it did not find (word|punc)*, now if I use my solution above it works, weird.